# Why is a blank line added before a description environment when placed in a footnote in ConTeXt?

Tags: lists, footnotes, context, description, context-mkiv

I would like to place a description environment inside a footnote, e.g.:

```
\definedescription[descr][headstyle=normal, style=normal, width=3em]
\starttext
    This is some text.\footnote{\startdescr{Label} This is a footnote.\stopdescr}
\stoptext
```

When I compile this code, it places the footnote number, but then skips an extra line before displaying the description environment, e.g.:

```
This is some text.~1

  -----
1
  Label   This is a footnote.
```

How can I get it to appear like this?

```
This is some text.~1

  -----
1 Label   This is a footnote.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default setup for `definitions` sets `before=\blank`; so you get a blank before `\startdesc`. You can get rid of it by setting `before=` in footnotes. However, that alone does not work correctly with the default setup. Both the footnotes (which are implemented as descriptions) and descriptions default to `alternative=left` to place the label. And the label of user-defined description get placed to the *right* of the footnote symbol, which, of course you do not want. One solution is to use another style for your own descriptions (I use `alternative=serried):

```
\definedescription[descr]
                  [headstyle=normal, style=normal, width=3em, alternative=serried]

\startsetups footnotedescription
  \setupdescription[descr][before=]
\stopsetups

\setupfootnotes[setups={footnotedescription}]

\starttext
    This is some text.\footnote{\startdescr{Label} This is a footnote.\stopdescr}
\stoptext
```